# Задача C++. Задача про кирпичи

Tags: c++

Задача не проходит один из тестов проверяющей системы.
В чём ошибка?

Условие:
[image: Условие]

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

bool comp(int a, int b) {
    return -(a-b);
}

void write(vector<long long> a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
}

int main()
{
    long long n, m;
    long long L = 0;
    long long sum = 0;
    long long k = 0;
    vector<long long> used;
    vector<long long> br;

    cin >> n >> m;
    for (long long i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        long long t;
        cin >> t;
        br.push_back(t);
        br.push_back(t);
        sum += t*2;
    }

    sort(br.begin(), br.end(), greater<int>());

    if (n < sum) {
        for (int j = 0; j < br.size(); j++) {
            for (int i = j; i < br.size(); i++) {

                if ( br[i] <= (n-L) ) {
                    used.push_back(br[i]);
                    L += br[i];
                    k++;
                }
                if (L == n) break;
            }
            if (L == n) {
                break;
            } else {
                k = 0;
                L = 0;
                used.clear();
            }
        }


        if (L == n) {
            cout << k << endl;
            write(used);
        } else {
            cout << 0;
        }
    } else if (n == sum) {
        cout << m*2 << endl;
        write(br);
    } else {
        cout << -1;
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! 1. текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса. 2. с вопросами по поводу функционирования проверящей системы следует обращаться к разработчикам/администраторам.

Comment: в условии, где написано: M попарно чисел - разве не имеется ввиду, что ввод состоит из M пар чисел, а не просто M чисел?

Comment: Во вторых pow(10, 9)  вполне  вмещается в  int,   просто  излишне брать память под long long

Comment: И это не тот алгоритм, который будет работать.

Comment: "Кипричей", "кипричей" [x]